# How to rename all file names to be the same in different subfolders?

Tags: batch-file

How can I change all file name to be the same from different folder like:

```
C:\Workspace\1\a.jpg
C:\Workspace\2\ab.doc
C:\Workspace\3\abc.jpg
```

to

```
C:\Workspace\1\scan.jpg
C:\Workspace\2\scan.doc
C:\Workspace\3\scan.jpg
```

Comment: What happens if `C:\Workspace\2` contains both ab.doc and c.jpg? Also, what is the use case for doing this? Why?

Comment: @lit if contains both, it will change to scan.doc and scan.jpg also. This is for make all the file as the same because some of file different name and hard to track in each folder.

Comment: @SyafiqLatif - Sorry, I gave the wrong example. What if `C:\Workspace\2` contains both a.jpg and b.jpg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a batch file for this task:

```
@echo off
set "SourceFolder=C:\Workspace"
if not exist "%SourceFolder%\1\*.jpg" goto EndBatch

for %%I in ("%SourceFolder%\1\*.jpg") do (
    ren "%%I" "scan.jpg" 2>nul
    if errorlevel 1 goto EndBatch
    goto RenameDOC
)

:RenameDOC
for %%I in ("%SourceFolder%\2\*.doc") do (
    ren "%%I" "scan.doc" 2>nul
    goto RenameJPG
)

:RenameJPG
for %%I in ("%SourceFolder%\3\*.jpg") do (
    ren "%%I" "scan.jpg" 2>nul
    goto EndBatch
)

:EndBatch
set "SourceFolder=
```

The batch file does nothing if it can't find a non hidden *.jpg file in directory `C:\Workspace\1`.

It renames the **first** found *.jpg file in directory `C:\Workspace\1` to `scan.jpg`. If that was not successful because of missing NTFS or file access permissions for this operation or there is already a file `scan.jpg` in this directory, the batch file does nothing else.

On success renaming **first** *.jpg file in directory `C:\Workspace\1` to `scan.jpg` the batch file next searches for **first** non hidden *.doc file in directory `C:\Workspace\2` and rename it to `scan.doc`. Independent on result of this rename operation the batch file continues with file renaming in next directory `C:\Workspace\3` on which again just **first** non hidden *.jpg file is renamed to `scan.jpg` without evaluating result of this rename operation.

Last the batch file deletes the environment variable defined at top and exits.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `ren /?`
- `set /?`

Answer (score 0):

```
get-childItem -recurse | Where {$_.extension -eq ".jpg"} | rename-item -NewName { "scan.jpg" }
```

Im using this method to solve this matter. Hopefully its work also to others. Im using powershell.